# $\int_{\Gamma}\frac{e^{z}dz}{z(z^{2}-1)}$ as $\Gamma$ is rectangle contour that does not passes through the points $0,1,-1$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, contour-integration, complex-integration

Find all possible values for $$\int_{\Gamma}\frac{e^{z}dz}{z(z^{2}-1)}$$ as $\Gamma$ is a rectangle contour that does not passes through the points $0,1,-1$.

**My attempt:**

we must divide the answer into cases.

Notice that given $\Gamma$ to be a rectangle, it can't be that $-1,1\in \Gamma \land 0\notin \Gamma$

---

**Case 1**: $-1,0,0 \notin \Gamma$

By Cauchy theorem,  $$\int_{\Gamma}\frac{e^{z}dz}{z(z^{2}-1)}= 0$$

for all the following cases we have to consider the direction of the contour, right or left, which means the sign (positive or negative) of the integrated.

---

**Case $2\space\text{and}\space 3$**: $-1\in \Gamma^{0}, 0,1\notin \Gamma$

Let $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{e^z}{z(z-1)}$, then
$$\int_{\Gamma}\frac{e^{z}dz}{z(z^{2}-1)} = \int_{\Gamma}\frac{f(z)dz}{z+1} = \pm 2\pi i(f(-1))=\pm\frac{\pi i}{e}$$

---

**Case $4\space\text{and}\space 5$**: $0\in \Gamma, 1,-1\notin \Gamma$

Let $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{e^z}{z^2-1}$, then
$$\int_{\Gamma}\frac{e^{z}dz}{z(z^{2}-1)} = \int_{\Gamma}\frac{f(z)dz}{z} = \pm 2\pi i(f(0))=\pm(2\pi i)$$

---

**Case $ 6 \space\text{and}\space 7$**: $1\in \Gamma^{0}, 0,-1\notin \Gamma$

Let $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{e^z}{z(z+1)}$, then
$$\int_{\Gamma}\frac{e^{z}dz}{z(z^{2}-1)} = \int_{\Gamma}\frac{f(z)dz}{z(z+1)} = \pm 2\pi i(f(1))=(\frac{e^{1}}{1(2)}) = \pm{\pi i e}$$

---

**Case $8\space\text{and}\space 9$**: $-1,0\in \Gamma, 1\notin \Gamma$

Let $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{e^z}{(z-1)}$, then
$$\int_{\Gamma}\frac{e^{z}dz}{z(z^{2}-1)} = \int_{\Gamma}\frac{f(z)dz}{z(z+1)}  
= \pm 2 \pi i(f(-1)+f(0))= \pm 2 \pi i (\frac{e^{-1}}{-2} + 1) = \pm  (\frac{-\pi i}{e}+ 2\pi i)$$

---

**Case $10\space\text{and}\space 11$**: $1,0\in \Gamma, -1\notin \Gamma$

Let $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{e^z}{(z+1)}$, then
$$\int_{\Gamma}\frac{e^{z}dz}{z(z^{2}-1)} = \int_{\Gamma}\frac{f(z)dz}{z-1} = \pm 2 \pi i(f(1)+f(0))= \pm 2 \pi i (\frac{e^{1}}{2} + 1) = \pm  (\pi i e+ 2\pi i)$$

---

**Case $12\space\text{and}\space13$**: $1,0,-1, \in \Gamma$

Let $\displaystyle f(z)={e^z}$, then
$$\int_{\Gamma}\frac{e^{z}dz}{z(z^{2}-1)} = \int_{\Gamma}\frac{f(z)dz}{z(z^2-1)} = \pm 2 \pi i(f(1)+f(0)+f(-1))= \pm 2 \pi i (e^{1} + e^{-1} + 1)$$

---

is that correct?

Comment: You are correct except for a notational mistake. You must write 1 belongs to interior of gamma not 1 belongs to gamma.

Comment: $1\in\Gamma^0$ not $1\in\Gamma$

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen yes

Comment: sorry, what do you mean exactly by "the rectangle traveled once"?

Comment: "$\Gamma $ is a rectangle" is a misnomer for "$\Gamma:t\mapsto \Gamma(t)$ is a parametric curve whose image is a rectangle (and this one can be traversed several times like the circle traversed $n$ times $[0,2\pi]\to \Bbb C,t\mapsto e^{int }$)